# HIKVISION ANPR Camera stream and attachments with python

Tags: python, python-requests, hikvision

I've got a hikvision camera that i subscribe to the message stream on /ISAPI/Event/notification/alertStream
I'm using python with the requests library to read the XML data that comes in through the feed,
I manage to read all the text however I dont know how to process the attachments,

my code is pretty simple,

```
auth = requests.auth.HTTPDigestAuth('<username>', '<password>')
url = 'http://<my camera ipaddress>/ISAPI/Event/notification/alertStream'

def streaming():
    resp = requests.Session().request("GET",url,stream=True,auth=auth,timeout=(3.05, 27))
    for chunk in resp.iter_lines(chunk_size=1):
        with open('stream2.txt', 'a') as f:
            if len(str(chunk)) > 0:
                f.writelines(str(datetime.now())+chr(9) + str(chunk) +"\r\n")
```

my question is how can I save the attachments correctly, I would like to do this without additional libraries if possible (with python),
I'm trying to lean python and camera integration, this is not for an assignment nor for commercial gain, but for me to further my knowledge,
Here's the some of the output i get,

```
2023-03-29 23:00:05.679670  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="anpr.xml"; filename="anpr.xml"
2023-03-29 23:00:05.684775  Content-Type: text/xml
2023-03-29 23:00:05.689310  Content-Length: 2300
2023-03-29 23:00:05.703378  <EventNotificationAlert version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.hikvision.com/ver20/XMLSchema">
2023-03-29 23:00:05.709876  <ipAddress>10.10.30.248</ipAddress>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.717521  <ipv6Address>::ffff:10.10.30.248</ipv6Address>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.722097  <portNo>80</portNo>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.727162  <protocol>HTTP</protocol>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.734291  <macAddress>c0:6d:ed:d6:66:ea</macAddress>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.739210  <channelID>1</channelID>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.746957  <dateTime>2023-03-29T23:00:05+02:00</dateTime>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.753371  <activePostCount>1</activePostCount>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.758773  <eventType>ANPR</eventType>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.764657  <eventState>active</eventState>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.771635  <eventDescription>ANPR</eventDescription>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.776217  <channelName>Camera 01</channelName>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.777747  <ANPR>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.780244  <country>151</country>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.783847  <licensePlate>abc12345</licensePlate>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.785877  <line>1</line>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.788732  <direction>forward</direction>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.791984  <confidenceLevel>98</confidenceLevel>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.794658  <plateType>unknown</plateType>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.797305  <plateColor>white</plateColor>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.800147  <licenseBright>132</licenseBright>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.802423  <dangmark>no</dangmark>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.805410  <twoWheelVehicle>no</twoWheelVehicle>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.808637  <threeWheelVehicle>no</threeWheelVehicle>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.812887  <plateCharBelieve>99,99,99,99,99,99,99,99</plateCharBelieve>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.815672  <vehicleType>truck</vehicleType>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.817995  <detectDir>8</detectDir>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.820421  <detectType>0</detectType>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.824007  <alarmDataType>0</alarmDataType>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.826361  <vehicleInfo>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.829057  <index>13</index>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.831795  <colorDepth>1</colorDepth>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.834094  <color>gray</color>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.836357  <length>0</length>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.839871  <vehicleLogoRecog>1566</vehicleLogoRecog>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.843527  <vehileSubLogoRecog>0</vehileSubLogoRecog>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.846263  <vehileModel>0</vehileModel>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.848252  </vehicleInfo>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.850383  <pictureInfoList>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.852427  <pictureInfo>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.856169  <fileName>licensePlatePicture.jpg</fileName>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.859190  <type>licensePlatePicture</type>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.861761  <dataType>0</dataType>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.864786  <picRecogMode>0</picRecogMode>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.868085  <absTime>20230329230005021</absTime>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.871822  <pId>2023032923000584400CN9QRDDWwnOtY</pId>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.873912  </pictureInfo>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.875944  <pictureInfo>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.879570  <fileName>detectionPicture.jpg</fileName>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.882544  <type>detectionPicture</type>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.885069  <dataType>0</dataType>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.887912  <picRecogMode>0</picRecogMode>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.891153  <absTime>20230329230005021</absTime>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.893086  <plateRect>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.894856  <X>271</X>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.896536  <Y>274</Y>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.898554  <width>97</width>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.900726  <height>65</height>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.902523  </plateRect>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.905970  <pId>2023032923000584500VpAHBvGGAgUFZ</pId>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.907836  </pictureInfo>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.909978  </pictureInfoList>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.914023  <originalLicensePlate>ND801259</originalLicensePlate>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.916348  <CRIndex>151</CRIndex>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.919842  <vehicleListName>otherList</vehicleListName>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.922678  <plateCategory></plateCategory>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.925114  <plateSize>0</plateSize>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.926558  </ANPR>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.931715  <UUID>2023032923000584400iUHr1My83rvfSxLGZazFvbZgEqBdhxNtr5AuF4dw7Z5Z</UUID>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.933803  <picNum>2</picNum>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.937598  <isDataRetransmission>false</isDataRetransmission>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.940092  </EventNotificationAlert>
2023-03-29 23:00:05.942502  --boundary
2023-03-29 23:00:05.949668  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="licensePlatePicture.jpg"; filename="2023032923000584400CN9QRDDWwnOtY.jpg"
2023-03-29 23:00:05.952106  Content-Type: image/jpeg
2023-03-29 23:00:05.954334  Content-Length: 23749
2023-03-29 23:00:05.958541  ÿØÿà JFIF      ÿÛ C 
2023-03-29 23:00:05.959549  
2023-03-29 23:00:05.960399  
2023-03-29 23:00:05.961163  
2023-03-29 23:00:05.962033  
2023-03-29 23:00:05.965041  ÿÛ C        
2023-03-29 23:00:05.965839  
2023-03-29 23:00:05.972325  ÿÀ  À0" ÿÝ  ÿÄ              
2023-03-29 23:00:05.976304  ÿÄ µ   } !1AQa"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚ 
2023-03-29 23:00:05.985370  %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ
```

I've tried to see how i can save a "Content-Disposition: form-data" but my searches seem to be fruitless,

Comment: I managed to write the code manually...
basically read the text portion of the file until you get to, an attachment
Then start reading the attachment and save it to a byte array, until you get a boundary 
 then save the byte array  to a file....
i just thought there may have been an easier way than doing the code byte at a time